# How to assign variable's value to "part" of other variable in loop for in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to enhance my bash scripting skills with raspberry pi, so doing some scripts.

In this script I want to take some information from user:
- number of relay's closings
- time for closing each relay
and trying to do it maximum in for loops just to be familiar with it.

I have a problem to assign a variable to a part of other variable.
You can see it in loop section where I'm trying to input sleep command. As I understad I have 4 variables in memory: `pausetime17`, `pausetime18`, `pausetime22`, and `pausetime23`, so I just want to go through them in loop:

```
from z in 17 18 22 23
do
    sleep $pausetim$z
done
```

But the error rises in shell. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

```
echo "Enter the number of repeats"
read numbertime
for k in 17 18 22 23
do
    echo "Enter time for relay $k"
    read pausetime$k
done

for j in 17 18 22 23
do
    echo $j > /sys/class/gpio/export
    echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$j/direction
done

for (( i=1; i<=$numbertime; i++ ))
do
    for z in 17 18 22 23
    do
        echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$z/value
        sleep $pausetime${!z}
        echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$z/value
        sleep $pausetime${!z}
    done
done    

for j in 17 18 22 23
do
echo $j > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
done
```

Comment: maybe you should use array variable. http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html

Comment: Yes, I thought of this method. Just wanted to know could I do it with simple variables for sporadic situations.

Comment: Please don't do this: Dynamically changing variable names or executable code leads to situations that are difficult to debug. Using an array is not difficult and the best option in this case.

Comment: @MichaelJaros I managed to do it with previous advice and it works. But I solved this task with array and it's definitely better way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments it may not be the good way to do however this can be done with variable indirection

```
 pausetime17=1
 z=17
 varname=pausetime$z

 echo ${!varname}
```

Since bash 4 variables can have the refname attribute

```
$ declare -n varref=pausetime$z
$ echo $varref
1
```

However assignments have effect on referenced variable

```
$ varref=10
$ echo $pausetime17
10
$ unset varref
$ echo $pausetime17
## nothing ##
```

Comment: Thank a lot. It works with your advise. I made like you wrote.            for z in 17 18 22 23
 do
  echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$z/value
  tempvar=pausetime$z
  sleep ${!tempvar}
  echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$z/value
  sleep ${!tempvar}
 done